# How do the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ change under variable transformation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

**Question**

I'm trying to answer the following question.

By setting $X = \alpha x + \beta y$ and $T = \gamma x + \delta y$, show that the PDE $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y} = 0$ can be transformed into $\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial T^2} - \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial X^2} = 0$, for $f(x,y) = F(\alpha x + \beta y, \gamma x + \delta y)$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are suitably chosen.

**Attempt**

My first step is to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) = 0$. My next aim is to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ in terms of $ \frac{\partial}{\partial X} $ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}$.

I do not understand how to do this. How can you understand how to achieve this in general under a change of variables? Eg, if I have new variables $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ then in general how can you work out how the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ are written in terms of the $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$?

Comment: I don't know why you want to do this. Why not just write $f_{xx}$ and $f_{xy}$ in terns of $F_{XX}$, $F_{XT}$, $F_{TT}$ (trivial by chain rule with the $X,T$ given) and then you have a linear combination of  $F_{XX}$, $F_{XT}$, $F_{TT}$ adding to $0$, find relation of $\alpha$, $\beta$ etc to get the coefft of $F_{XT}$ zero... (I think it's clear that we'll get $c=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the chain rule. You will have, for example,
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$

Comment: @Arthur well, I also thought of using $X$ and $T$, but the part of the question asking about any change of variables uses $u$ and $v$ instead, so I guess I just got carried away by that. Feel free to edit the answer if you think it will be better that way.